JavaScript Heap Out of Memory Error: Allocation Failure
I'm using NestJS with Node.js version v20.12.1, and every time I run my project, I encounter an "insufficient memory" error. I'm not sure where this issue is coming from. Can you help me figure out how to resolve it?
The error as below.
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
----- Native stack trace -----
1: 00007FF60DA7C81B node::SetCppgcReference+17979
2: 00007FF60D9E6674 DSA_meth_get_flags+89316
3: 00007FF60E464871 v8::Isolate::ReportExternalAllocationLimitReached+65
4: 00007FF60E44DFC8 v8::Function::Experimental_IsNopFunction+1336
5: 00007FF60E2AFA70 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+659328
6: 00007FF60E2ACAF8 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+647176
7: 00007FF60E2C1E0A v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+733978
8: 00007FF60E2C2687 v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+736151
9: 00007FF60E2D0F7F v8::Platform::SystemClockTimeMillis+795791
10: 00007FF60DF91CA5 v8::CodeEvent::GetFunctionName+116773
11: 00007FF60E51619E v8::PropertyDescriptor::writable+677998
12: 00007FF60E4E2115 v8::PropertyDescriptor::writable+464869
13: 00007FF60E484E13 v8::PropertyDescriptor::writable+83171
14: 00007FF5E83DE857
RpcExitError: Process 11824 exited with code 134
Issues checking service aborted - probably out of memory. Check the `memoryLimit` option in the ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin configuration. If increasing the memory doesn't solve the issue, it's most probably a bug in the TypeScript.

Have you tried to follow what's indicated on this link : https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-heap-out-of-memory ? Using the --max-old-space-size option
